# How to improve this Rx FolderWatcher?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, filesystemwatcher

I started my sample from the one provided here:http://www.jaylee.org/post/2012/08/26/An-update-to-matthieumezil-Rx-and-the-FileSystemWatcher.aspx
but the issue is that if you are watching a folder that has many files being modified/created/deleted at all time, it will never return an event since the throttle will never stop.

What I needed is to create a new temporary stream for each files being changed and only send the last event (if it is a delete event, we don't notify).

I think my sample is working, but since it is the first time I use Rx, I'd like to have some feedback on how I could simplify it.

Here it is:

```
public class FileWatcher
{
    public class FileChangedEvent
    {
        public string FullPath { get; private set; }
        public bool IsFileDeleted { get; private set; }

        public FileChangedEvent(string path, bool isFileDeleted = false)
        {
            FullPath = path;
            IsFileDeleted = isFileDeleted;
        }
    }

    public static IObservable<FileChangedEvent> ObserveFolderChanges(string path, string filter, TimeSpan throttle)
    {
        return Observable.Create<FileChangedEvent>(
            observer =>
            {
                var fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path, filter) { EnableRaisingEvents = true };

                var sources = CreateSources(fileSystemWatcher);

                var fileSources = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Subject<FileChangedEvent>>();
                return sources.Merge().Subscribe(fileChange =>
                {
                    Subject<FileChangedEvent> fileSubject = fileSources.GetOrAdd(fileChange.FullPath, (key) =>
                    {
                        //Create a new stream for this file.
                        var addedFileSubject = new Subject<FileChangedEvent>();
                        addedFileSubject.Throttle(throttle).Subscribe(lastFileChange =>
                        {
                            if (lastFileChange != null)
                            {
                                Subject<FileChangedEvent> dummy;
                                fileSources.TryRemove(lastFileChange.FullPath, out dummy);

                                //Only send the event if the file was not deleted.
                                if (!lastFileChange.IsFileDeleted)
                                {
                                    observer.OnNext(lastFileChange);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        return addedFileSubject;
                    });

                    fileSubject.OnNext(fileChange);
                });
            }
        );
    }

    private static IObservable<FileChangedEvent>[] CreateSources(FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher)
    {
        return new[] 
        { 
            Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs >(handler => fileWatcher.Created += handler, handler => fileWatcher.Created -= handler)
                        .Select(ev => new FileChangedEvent(ev.EventArgs.FullPath)), 

            Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs >(handler => fileWatcher.Deleted += handler, handler => fileWatcher.Deleted -= handler)
                        .Select(ev => new FileChangedEvent(ev.EventArgs.FullPath, true)),

            Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs >(handler => fileWatcher.Changed += handler, handler => fileWatcher.Changed -= handler)
                        .Select(ev => new FileChangedEvent(ev.EventArgs.FullPath)),

            //The rename source needs to send a delete event for the old file name.
            Observable.Create<FileChangedEvent>(nameChangedObserver =>
            {
                return Observable.FromEventPattern<RenamedEventHandler, RenamedEventArgs>(handler => fileWatcher.Renamed += handler, handler => fileWatcher.Renamed -= handler)
                    .Subscribe(ev =>
                    {
                        nameChangedObserver.OnNext(new FileChangedEvent(ev.EventArgs.FullPath));
                        nameChangedObserver.OnNext(new FileChangedEvent(ev.EventArgs.OldFullPath, true));
                    });
            }),

            Observable.FromEventPattern<ErrorEventHandler, ErrorEventArgs >(handler => fileWatcher.Error += handler, handler => fileWatcher.Error -= handler)
                        .SelectMany(ev => Observable.Throw<FileChangedEvent>(ev.EventArgs.GetException()))
        };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fileWatcher =
            FileWatcher.ObserveFolderChanges("Test Path Here", "*.*", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
                        .Subscribe(fce => { if(fce != null) Console.WriteLine("Changed :" + fce.FullPath); }, e => Debug.WriteLine(e));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The use case of this is to be notified when a file is done being uploaded on the file path.

So, my questions:
1) Is it possible to simplify this?
2) Am I leaking something?
3) Is there a big performance loss versus doing this without Rx?

Thanks!

Comment: Such questions are better posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Holger [Vote to close because the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, not because it belongs somewhere else](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286591/1310566). Voting to close because it belongs somewhere else can cause situations where the question is closed on two places. It is okay to redirect people to other  sites, but don't vote to close with that reason.

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg: then I’d vote to close because it’s off-topic and add an additional comment pointing at the other site and the situation has changed in what way, exactly? By the way, my vote *is* recorded as “off-topic”, just with a custom comment.

Comment: @Holger I know, I noticed that your comment was an off-topic vote. It is better to vote to close as *too broad* and then add the comment. Because *too broad* is a valid close reason for this question, but "better posted at Code Review" is not a reason to close a question.

Comment: IMO it doesn't seem too broad or off-topic.  The bottom of the post asks pretty specific questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are leaking the `FileSystemWatcher` and yes it can also be simplified to eliminate all the futzing around with the dictionary and subjects.

Use `Observable.Using` to manage the lifetime of the watcher.  And use `GroupBy` to get rid of the dictionary of subjects:

```
public static IObservable<FileChangedEvent> ObserveFolderChanges(string path, string filter, TimeSpan throttle)
{
    return Observable.Using(
        () => new FileSystemWatcher(path, filter) { EnableRaisingEvents = true },
        fileSystemWatcher => CreateSources(fileSystemWatcher)
            .Merge()
            .GroupBy(c => c.FullPath)
            .SelectMany(fileEvents => fileEvents
                .Throttle(throttle)
                .Where(e => !e.IsFileDeleted)));
}
```

Comment: Additionally, that merge() probably belongs inside the CreateSources(..) method. I would additionally suggest that this is a great case for nested sequences i.e. an outer sequence that produces an inner sequence when a file is created. The inner sequence produces values on modifications, and completes when the file is deleted.

Comment: This answer seems to be exactly what I needed. It also helped me understand the SelectMany and have a better grasp of Rx.Net.  

@LeeCampbell I agree that the merge should be in the CreateSources(), but could you point me to an example of what you are talking about in the second part of your comment? Thanks!

Comment: Nested sequences are covered here http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html